# Why does Xcode autocompletion suggest .m files when importing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Just wondering -

When you start to type `#import "`

Xcode suggests `.m` files and `.h` files. I just had a few hours of frustration after mistakenly importing `.m` file.

Is that a bad design? Can you import `.m` files?

Comment: bad design for sure, even if it's allowed by the language.  auto-anything ought to exclude the edge cases.  go through all code ever written and count the percent of imports of things other than headers.  1%? less?

Comment: Because it's not very smart.  You certainly can import .m files, and there are cases where that makes sense, but those cases are rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import any files. `#import` is just a preprocessor directive that basically says "include contents of the file I tell you into the current file". There are some include guards as well, but the import does just that - it imports the file you tell it to.

Importing the header with .h file is probably more of a convenience/convention (please don't beat me for this, I'm just guessing) unless there's some C/C++ standard that says otherwise.

Comment: Importing the header as opposed to the implementation file avoids redefinition of everything there. Redeclaring (what is done in the header) is fine, but defining something (as done in implementation file) multiple times by including it everywhere causes conflicts.